# jQuery or JS to show larger image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a way too display images like google does. when someone hovers over an image, an larger view is shown I would like to know how I can achieve this.

Comment: "Like google does." Oh, that clears it up. "Give me the code" Yes, sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are tons of plugins out there if you still aren't very good at jQuery yet. The [imgPreview](http://james.padolsey.com/demos/imgPreview/full/) plugin seems like it would fit your needs. Another really slick looking one is [ZoomerGallery](http://addyosmani.com/blog/zoomer-gallery-a-jquery-plugin-for-displaying-images-with-flash-like-zooming-effects/).

On the other hand, if you want to do it exactly like Google, just go to the page where it does what you want, view source, and grab the script they are using.

Comment: imgPreview is exactly what I need! Thanks JohnFx :)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/HmTrw/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("img").hover(
    function () {
        //mouse enter 
        //do animations
    },
    function () {
        //mouse leave
        //do animations
    }
);
```

Thats what i'd look at. Also see here:
http://api.jquery.com/hover/